# How to activate a port . Let's say (123 NTP on my machine ) . with ufw enable 123 (or 123/tcp or 123/udp) ? That is for firewall or that is all?

Tags: linux

I want to know how to activate a port ( dosent matter what port 43,53,etc )

How i do it ?

is ufw enable port   (port/tcp or port/udp ) enough ? Or i need it to do something more ?

after i run ufw status verbose . Is showing me that port is in the ALLOW In bracket . But if i type let's say nmap -p 1-5000 my_ip  it dosen't show the service or with netstat -tlupn ( or should i activate the service first  ?  and then should i see it )

sorry for this big mess of words . HOpe you have a great day , all of you !

Comment: Do you use ufw? `sorry for this big mess of words . HOpe` Don't you have a English spellchecker that would underline words like `verbosa` and `dosen't`?

Comment: i write from my phone . so the spellchecker is from my native language (spanish ) and is changing the words like crazy . is ufw enable verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your service first (an active listener must be running on said port). The firewall only allow/reject packages - it does not create listeners.